# Change div background color on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change div color on click but it is not working:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function data(){
                var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('newdata').innerHTML;
                alert(MyDiv1)   
                if(MyDiv1==1) {
                    document.getElementsById('newdata').style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="newdata" style="background-color: red; width: 100px;height: 50px;">
            1
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="data();">Logout</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where am I wrong here?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="newdata" style="background-color: red; width: 100px;height: 50px;">
            1
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="data();">Logout</a>
    </body>
</html>
  <script>
       function data(){

       document.getElementById('newdata').style.backgroundColor = "green";

       }
  </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n2uk4br1/

1) Script at the end;

2) Element not Elements

3) Call the right div name

4) That alert and if don't have a purpose

Comment: i want to check condition if i =1 then only change color

Comment: then leave the condition and make the other changes

Answer (score 0):

it should be `newdata`

```
 document.getElementById('newdata').style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

so your function will be

```
function data(){
                var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('newdata').innerHTML;
                alert(MyDiv1)   
                if(MyDiv1==1) {
                    document.getElementById('newdata').style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }
            }
```

Comment: it should be `element`

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of problems with your attempt. The following snippet does what you want:

```js
function data(){
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('newdata');
  var content = myDiv.innerHTML;
  if (content.trim() === "1")  {
    myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="newdata" style="background-color: red; width: 100px;height: 50px;">
  1
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="data();">Logout</a>
```

Firstly, you must be careful to distinguish between your `<div>` element and its contents. I have put the two into separate variables. I have used `.trim()` to remove any leading and trailing spaces from the contents of the `<div>` and also used the strict comparison `===`.